# Get value assigned to textbox from javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following script being used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#<%=txtEnd.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
             showsTime: true,
             ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",
             daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
             align: "BR",
             electric: false,
             singleClick: false,
             displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
             button: ".next()"
         });
</script>
```

When I access txtEnd.Text it's empty. How do I go about getting the value that gets placed in the box?

Code behind

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
```

Comment: document ready is executed only once when page loads but I still I failed to find in your sample code which event you are accessing the content of your textbox

Comment: i'm accessing it from the codebehind on a button press

Comment: Does the textbox have anything inside it on the page _before_ you press the button to submit it back to the server?

Comment: Yes the box contains the date and time

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form[txtStart.UniqueID]);
```

Comment: Seems like that only reason you need to do that is because you are overwriting the value of `txtStart.Text` on post back. The normal way to fix your problem is to simply not do that. Should probably add some different handling in case of bad date time parsing too.